# String replace replacing all occurrences of sub string in java

Tags: java

I have this java code

```
    String s3="10100111001";
    String s4="1001";
    String s5="0";
    System.out.println(s3);
    int last_index=3; //To replace only the last 

    while(last_index>=0) {
        last_index=s3.indexOf(s4,last_index);
        System.out.println("B:" +last_index);
        if(last_index>=0)
        {

            s3=s3.replace(s3.substring(last_index,(last_index+s4.length())),s5);
            last_index=last_index+s4.length();
            System.out.println("L:"+last_index);
            continue;
        }

        else
        {
            continue;
        }

    }
    System.out.println(s3);
```

Ideally, this code should replace only the last occurence of `1001` but its replacing both the occurrences of `1001`

My output is `10010` but it should be `10100110`. where I am going wrong?

Comment: WHy don't you just use `.lastIndexOf()` to find the last occurrence?

Comment: If there are more than two, it goes wrong right? I want to replace substring at specified index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression

```
s3.substring(last_index,(last_index+s4.length()))
```

returns `"1001"` string. Calling `replace` with that string as the argument will perform the replacement throughout the entire string, so it would replace both occurrences.

To fix your solution, you can replace the call of `replace` with a composition of three substrings:

- from zero to `last_index`
- `s5`
- from `last_index+4` to the end.

Like this:

```
s3=s3.substring(0, last_index) + s5 + s3.substring(last_index+s4.length());
```

Comment: So how to modify the code so that only the specified part is replaced?